# How to find Outlook messages that require a vote response

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

Looking to either search or filter (rule) Outlook messages that contain voting buttons (especially ones I've not responded to yet) so that I will notice them and click the appropriate voting button (I find the little blue "Click here to vote" button on the message preview is very easy to miss).

The messages don't have a specific importance or priority, and while they all come from the same account, not everything from that account is a vote request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter on the "All Mail Items" field "Originator Delivery Requested".

It includes all response types (including request read receipt). It's the closest I could find.

Comment: I didn't have luck with the "Originator Delivery Requested" field, but the "Receipt Requested" field proved useful. It also included all response types as you said, but further filtering on the sender got it down to just vote emails. Now if I can just exclude the ones I've already responded to, it would be perfect.

Comment: You could just respond right away.  Then you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: True, since the search folder should become bold when there's an unread message in it, I can just make sure to go read and vote on the new message when it goes bold.

Comment: You can also flag those messages that you don't vote on right away. If you pick one particular flag for those messages, you can filter on that. Once you've voted, remove the flag. Problem solved.